# sqlite.get() results in TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

When trying to execute a sql.get() call it works in some places, but not in others and I can't seem to figure out what's the difference.
The database is sucessfully opened or at least I never got an error and it never gets closed. I also use Discord.js in the second (working example), not sure if that is relevant, though.
In this example it doesn't work.
test.js:

```
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("./data.sqlite");

exports.getItemID = function(item) {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
        sql.get(`SELECT * FROM items WHERE name="${item}"`).then(row => {
            console.log(`do stuff`);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.error;
            reject(e);
        })
    });
}

exports.getItemID("Coins").then(itemID => {
    console.log(itemID);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Stacktrace:

```
$ node test.js 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null
    at Promise (/Users/julianveerkamp/node_modules/sqlite/main.js:225:18)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Database.get (/Users/julianveerkamp/node_modules/sqlite/main.js:224:12)
    at /Users/julianveerkamp/workspace/test-bot/test.js:6:13
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.getItemID (/Users/julianveerkamp/workspace/test-bot/test.js:5:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/julianveerkamp/workspace/test-bot/test.js:15:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
```

But when I call a function with

```
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("./data.sqlite");
// other stuff
let commandFile = require(`./commands/command.js`);
commandFile.run(client, message, args);
// other stuff
```

it works just fine.

command.js:

```
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("./data.sqlite");

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    sql.get(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userID ="${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
        // Do stuff with row
    }).catch(() => {
        console.error;
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not the problem, but just FYI, that code is falling prey to the "new Promise anti-pattern." There's no reason for `getItemID` to create a new promise, it already has a promise chain (from `get`).

Comment: Does the line `// Do stuff with row` exist in your code when you run the app? The stacktrace's  `/Users/user/workspace/test-bot/test.js:8:13` line  looks suspicious!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. I'll have to read more about the "new Promise anti-pattern" and promises in general, as I'm fairly new to node.js and javascript.

Comment: @undefined do you mean the `at Object.exports.getItemID`? The `// do stuff with row` is just a check if the row exists, and if it exist `let itemID = row.itemID`, but even if all that is replaced with `console.log(`do stuff`)` it fails. I'll update the post with actual runnable and the correct stacktrace.

Comment: Looks like something is happening behind the scenes, it's not the `sql.get` in your code that throws the error.

Comment: @undefined when just executing the sql.get part I get a different [stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/XpxHEech)

Comment: It's the 225th line of the `../node_modules/sqlite/main.js` file which throws the error. I haven't used that library so unfortunately I have no idea what's happening in that file. Try with executing different SQL query and check what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151959/discussion-between-julian-veerkamp-and-undefined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug in `sqlite` so I went ahead and used `sqlite3` instead and wrapped/promisified the functions myself with util.promisify().

```
const util = require('util');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

var db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.sqlite');

db.get = util.promisify(db.get);
db.run = util.promisify(db.run);

exports.getItemID = function(item) {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
        db.get(`SELECT * FROM items WHERE name="${item}"`).then(row => {
            console.log(`do stuff`);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.error;
            reject(e);
        });
    });
}

exports.getItemID("Coins").then(itemID => {
    console.log(itemID);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Note: The new Promise inside the function is not necessary. One could just return the promise from the get function.