# discord js bot coin system | sqlite eror

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord

**CODE:**

```
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const tokenfile = require("./token.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("./coin.sqlite");

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();


fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {

  if(err) console.log(err);
  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("Не удалось найти команды!.");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} загружен!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});


bot.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;

  let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let cmd = messageArray[0];
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);
  let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length));
  if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);

});

sql.get(`SELECT * FROM coins WHERE userId = [message.author.id]`).then(row => {
  if (!row) { // Can't find the row.
    sql.run("INSERT INTO coins (userId, coins) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.author.id, 0]);
  } else {  // Can find the row.
    let curAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) +0.3 (row.coins + curAmt);
    if (curAmt > row.coins) {
      row.coins = curAmt;
      sql.run(`UPDATE coins SET coins = ${row.coins + curAmt}, WHERE userId = [message.author.id]`);
    }
    sql.run(`UPDATE coins SET coins = ${row.coins + curAmt} WHERE userId = [message.author.id]`);
  }
}).catch(() => {
  console.error; // Log those errors.
  sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coins (userId TEXT, coins INTEGER)").then(() => {
    sql.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, coins) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.author.id, 0]);
  });
});

bot.login(tokenfile.token);
```

and i got those error:

**ERROR:**

```
(node:14328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of null
    at Promise (C:\Users\Илья\Desktop\JyxoBot\Jyxo\node_modules\sqlite\main.js:219:19)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Database.run (C:\Users\Илья\Desktop\JyxoBot\Jyxo\node_modules\sqlite\main.js:218:12)
    at sql.get.then.catch (C:\Users\Илья\Desktop\JyxoBot\Jyxo\index.js:67:7)
    at <anonymous>
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
(node:14328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
```

This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:14328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("./coin.sqlite");
```

To

```
const sql = require("sqlite");
const db = sql.open("./coin.sqlite");
```

Then use `db` instead of `sql` in the rest of the script. `db.get`, `db.run` etc

Comment: TypeError: db.get is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Илья\Desktop\JyxoBot\Jyxo\index.js:54:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: @Ilya maybe try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692757/sqlite-get-results-in-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-null